# Ordering SQLite3 Database greatest to least

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

Im trying to make a discord command that gets a column of a database greatest to least and gets the top 10 results, its working but its not printing in order greatest to least.

```py
cursor.execute(f"SELECT bal, user_id FROM moneyTable WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} ORDER BY bal DESC LIMIT 10")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

My result is

```
[('635', '673990922945560599'), ('400', '317652126471815168'), ('200', '323669516489850882'), ('15000', '539305505445642250'), ('1260', '448573840893804614'), ('1000', '531664615755612161'), ('100', '419300570235666432'), ('100', '412106756349624331'), ('100', '408674114958524417'), ('100', '358517557772156929')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the data type of `bal` is `TEXT` so it is ordered alphabetically.
You must convert `bal` to an integer either by adding `0` or explicitly:

```
SELECT bal, user_id 
FROM moneyTable 
WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} 
ORDER BY bal + 0 DESC LIMIT 10
```

or:

```
SELECT bal, user_id 
FROM moneyTable 
WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} 
ORDER BY CAST(bal AS INTEGER) DESC LIMIT 10
```